# Is there a way to find soft copy of this vintage photograph?

Tags: rama

This photo has been in our house for 3 generations.
I have been trying to find a soft copy to print for my new house.
There are lots of photos online for ram darbar, but the face shape and the aesthetics are way off.
Can someone help? I am happy to pay royalties for stock photos.
Thanks in advance.
[ram darbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLIl.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KnLIl.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's a match on eBay -- https://www.ebay.com/itm/402154781817.

For posterity, it's noted as being "India Vintage 50's Print RAMA SITA HANUMAN B G Sharma 14in x 20in"

[image: India Vintage 50's Print RAMA SITA HANUMAN B G Sharma 14in x 20in]

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think this [image](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTuA3eNrNfLdUu-fIwrTyykWan71s958-tq3w&usqp=CAU) and [image]is close enough.

You can find many such images in Google Pictures Search Engine only.

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..